# How do I aggregate the number of occurrences of an ObjectID in array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections; `users` and `communities`. My users can be linked to many communities so I have `linkedCommunities` as an array in the User schema as such:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  linkedCommunities: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Community'
    }
  ]
});
```

On my `communities` view I want to display the number of `users` linked to each community, so it would read something like:

```
| Community   | Number of users |
| ---------   | --------------- |
| Community 1 | 45              | 
| Community 2 | 78              |
| Community 4 | 107             |
```

Ideally when I do a find on the `Community` model I want a field called something like `linkedUserCount`.

I'm sure I can achieve this using `aggregate` somehow but I'm struggling to find the right pipeline operators and order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve required result by using following mongodb query:

```
db.users.aggregate( [ 
  { 
    $unwind : "$linkedCommunities" 
  },
  {
    $group : {
      _id : "$linkedCommunities",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      community: "$_id",
      count: "$count"
    }
  }
] )
```

Give it a try and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: This is perfect for giving me the counts. Thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to link it all up. 

Answer (score 2):

Here Maybe Can Help u,

```
users.aggregate([
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "Community",
            localField: "linkedCommunities",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "linkedcommunities"
        }}
,{
    $unwind: "$linkedCommunities"
},
{
    $group : {
        _id : "$linkedCommunities",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        community: "$_id",
        count: "$count"
    }
}]}
```